# how to change database version from 655 to 612?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Error -

> *mdf file can not be opened because it is version 655, this version
>   support 612 or earlier*

Note :

I am created this database file using SQL Server 2005 and later that file is opened in SQL Server 2008 then automatically change version from 612 to 655.

But I currently want to open that file in SQL Server 2005.

Any solution is possible then help me.

Comment: You **cannot** with any method, tool, trick or hack get a SQL Server file from a newer version (655) to be opened in an earlier version (612) - you just **cannot** do it. No way. You'll need to use the **same** version of SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading an `mdf` is a one-way process. You'll have to go back to a backup, an earlier version of the file or recreate it.

I'm guessing you don't have backups or an earlier version of the file (nobody posting "how do I get *something* back" on these sites knows what a backup is).

As far as recreating goes, you can attach the database to a SQL Server 2008 instance (or later) and then use SQL Server Management Studio to export the database into a blank database on an '05 instance.

From within Management Studio use the [Generate Scripts Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). You can use this wizard to build queries that will reconstruct the database. Make sure you choose to script *Schema and Data* and set the destination server version as SQL Server 2005.

Alternatively, you can use the [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) although it may not bring all your database objects across.